# The "Abstract" appears twice in the bookmark

Tags: thesis, bookmarks, abstract

I write my thesis in English in German. So I should write one Germany abstract and then one English version. But when I add a them in the bookmark, the "Abstract" appears twice, also the "Zusammenfassung" (Germany "Abstract"). Please see the figure below. The first "Abstract" in bookmark will index the title page of the documents, which is wrong. The second "Abstract" can correctly index the contents, i.g. the abstract of the documents. So, the first "Abstract" in the bookmark is wrong and should be removed. Can someone solve it? Thanks advance.

[image]

I use Texstudio as the interface, miktex is the distribution, plattform is windos10. The source code are written like following.

```
% !TeX document-id = {72e5695d-c860-48d1-aaec-bdabcc82c0dd}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]

\documentclass[english, cd=nocolor]{tudscrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
Title page

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\pagenumbering{roman}
% abstract
\TUDoption{abstract}{section}%{section, multiple}
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain} % for page number
\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
\par Germany abstract.
\end{otherlanguage}
\nextabstract[english]
\par    English abstract.
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{english}
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents

% Inhalt
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{ Introduction }
\par This is the introduction.
\section{ Motivation }
\par This is motivation.
\section{ Thesis outline }
\par This is outline.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The class has a `tocmultiple` option with which you get just one ToC entry. I.e. with

```
\TUDoption{abstract}{section,tocmultiple}
```

you get

[image: output of code]

```
% !TeX document-id = {72e5695d-c860-48d1-aaec-bdabcc82c0dd}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]

\documentclass[english, cd=nocolor]{tudscrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
Title page

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\pagenumbering{roman}
% abstract
\TUDoption{abstract}{section,tocmultiple}
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain} % for page number
\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
Germany abstract.
\end{otherlanguage}
\nextabstract[english]
English abstract.
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{english}
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents

% Inhalt
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{ Introduction }
\par This is the introduction.
\section{ Motivation }
\par This is motivation.
\section{ Thesis outline }
\par This is outline.
\end{document}
```

Comment: After adding tocmultiple in the TUDoption, only one "Zusammenfassung/Abstract" is shown in the bookmark, which is very good. But the problem is, when I touch the "Zusammenfassung/Abstract" in bookmark, it index to the title page rather than the abstract page. Do you know why?

Comment: @Xiaodi Ehm, no, I don't. You could ask a new question specifically about that, or post a bug-report at https://github.com/tud-cd/tudscr/issues.

Comment: The issue is here solved. https://github.com/tud-cd/tudscr/issues/30